# How to setup git repository and permissions for multiple projects and developer groups

Tags: git, permissions, repository, version-control, project-planning

With Subversion one can setup access permissions per directory within repository. So eg. one group can have commit access to directory A, read on B - with exception that DevA has also commit permissions on B.

How can one setup such a structure and permissions for Git repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gitosis](http://swik.net/gitosis) can help you there. (The page seems to be down currently but the source is still available at http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git.)

Comment: Yes, Gitosis is the way to go. +1